# CANNOT USE LocalBinder CLASS IN ANDROID STUDIO PACKAGE DOES NOT EXISTS

Tags: android

HOW to make localbinder class accessible or how to add a library to access the LocalBinder please give me answer

Comment: No need to shout at us!

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html, a local binder class is a local class that you write as part of your application.  It is required to extend the `Binder` class, and it is conventional to declare it as a *local class*.  The actual class name for your local binder class is your choice.

Note:

- There is no library to add to "get" a local binder class.
- There is no way to "make the class accessible".
- You just write it yourself.

If this is not clear to you now, please review the documentation I linked to above.

Comment: but i can't call the LocalBinder class that says the package doesnt exists

Comment: You never said what package didn't exist...